# Como limpar o valor de um INPUT após selecionar o radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Possuo dois **radiobuttons**, os quais possuem a função de mostrar/esconder um **input** cada, esses dois inputs não podem receber valores juntos, apenas o input que está dentro do radiobutton selecionado, gostaria que quando selecionasse um radiobutton apagasse o input do outro radiobutton, tem alguma maneira simples de fazer isso?

**código html:**

```
<input type="radio" name="formapag" value="debito" id="deb" onclick="document.getElementById('debito').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('credito').style.display='none';" />Venda
<input type="number" placeholder="R$0,00" min="0,01" step="0.01" name="debito" id="debito" placeholder="valor" style="display:none;">
<input type="radio" name="formapag" value="credito" id="cred" onclick="document.getElementById('debito').style.display='none';document.getElementById('credito').style.display='inline';" />Compra
<input type="number" placeholder="R$0,00" min="0,01" step="0.01" name="credito" id="credito" placeholder="valor" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Esses `radio` têm o mesmo `name`? Podes mostrar o HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo você separar seu HTML e JavaScript, por questões de legibilidade.
Logo, pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
(function () { 
   let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-limpar-inputs');
   for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
     radioButtons[i].addEventListener('click', limparInputs);
   }
  
   function limparInputs () {
     let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.limpar-ao-selecionar-radio');
     for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       inputs[i].value = '';
     }
   }
})();
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio-limpar-inputs" name="formapag" value="debito" id="deb" onclick="document.getElementById('debito').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('credito').style.display='none';" />Venda</a>
<input type="number" class="limpar-ao-selecionar-radio" placeholder="R$0,00" min="0,01" step="0.01" name="debito" id="debito" placeholder="valor" style="display:none;">
<br><br><input type="radio" class="radio-limpar-inputs" name="formapag" value="credito" id="cred" onclick="document.getElementById('debito').style.display='none';document.getElementById('credito').style.display='inline';" />Compra</a>
<input type="number" class="limpar-ao-selecionar-radio" placeholder="R$0,00" min="0,01" step="0.01" name="credito" id="credito" placeholder="valor" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode criar uma função que executa isso:

```
document.getElementById("id_do_seu_input").value = "";
```

por ex:

```
function zeraMeuID(){

     document.getElementById("id_do_seu_input").value = "";

}
```

ai no click do botão vc coloca chamando essa função

Answer (score 1):

É só adicionar comandos extras em cada `onclick` que você já usa respectivamente:

```
document.getElementById('credito').value=''
document.getElementById('debito').value=''
```

Ficando assim:

```html
<input type="radio" name="formapag" value="debito" id="deb" onclick="document.getElementById('debito').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('credito').style.display='none';document.getElementById('credito').value=''" />Venda
<input type="number" placeholder="R$0,00" min="0,01" step="0.01" name="debito" id="debito" placeholder="valor" style="display:none;">
<input type="radio" name="formapag" value="credito" id="cred" onclick="document.getElementById('debito').style.display='none';document.getElementById('credito').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('debito').value=''" />Compra
<input type="number" placeholder="R$0,00" min="0,01" step="0.01" name="credito" id="credito" placeholder="valor" style="display:none;">
```